# Crear un ejecutable a partir de un script en python (NumPy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, compilar, anaconda

perdón que parezca una duda muy simple, pero es la primera vez que hago esto y estoy teniendo dificultades. He creado con spyder, un software que trae anaconda, una calculadora de sistemas de ecuaciones, en la que he usado el módulo numpy, y al guardarlo y ejecutarlo en una consola aparece el siguiente error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calc_sist_ec.py", line 13, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Por lo que veo no puedo acceder al módulo de numpy desde fuera de spyder, me gustaría saber si pudiese crear un .exe con este código y ejecutarlo en cualquier equipo (Windows) a ser posible que no tenga instalado python

```
import numpy as np

print(" ")
print("Calculadora de sistemas de ecuaciones (x,y)")
print("Autor: ---")
print("v.1.0")
print(" ")
print("-INSTRUCCIONES-")
print(" ")
print("1º.-Escribe los coeficientes del primer sistema, sin parte literal (Escribir los terminos uno a uno)")

var1=int(input("T1="))
var2=int(input("T2="))
var3=int(input("T3="))

print(" ")
print("2º.-Ahora, escribe los del segundo sistema")
print(" ")

var4=int(input("T1="))
var5=int(input("T2="))
var6=int(input("T3="))

a=np.array([[var1,var2],[var4,var5]])#a=ecuaciones con coeficientes

b=np.array([var3,var6])#b=ecuaciones con coeficientes

c=np.linalg.solve(a,b)#numpy.algebra_lineal_resolver(var_a,var_b)

print(" ")

print(c)#imprime el resultado
print(" ")
print("Nota: El primer resultado siempre será (x), y el segundo (y)")
```

Perdón por esta duda tan simple, gracias de antemano.

Comment: El código es ejecutable en cualquier sistema que tenga un intérprete Python y NumPy instalado. Spyder estará usando un entorno virtual propio pero  en tu instalación del sistema de Python no tienes NumPy instalado. Para crear un "exe"  mírate [Pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) y [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (freezing) o [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html) (este último crea código C++ y lo compila).

Comment: Por cierto, ya que python es un lenguaje interpretado y no se puede realmente "compilar" en el sentido tradicional del término, propongo que cambies el título de la pregunta a: "Crear un ejecutable a partir de un script python (que usa numpy)", o similar.

Answer (score 1):

Debes asegurarte que en la terminal que ejecutas el código estés usando el python que trae Anaconda, si no lo tienes por defecto este usará el python del sistema que puede no sea la misma versión que usaste para crear el script o en tu caso que no tenga instalado numpy.